# BeautifulSoup (bs4): How to ignore ending tag in malformed HTML

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautifulsoup (bs4) to scrap HTML page. It has list `<ul>` which has `<li>` that holds some interesting link (href).

**Snippet**:

```
<ul>
 <!-- C 1-3 --></p>
 <li>
   <a href="http://LINK1" target="_blank">Link1 description</a>
 </li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <!-- E 1-2-3-6 --></p>
 <li>
  <a href="LINK-2" target="_blank">Link-2 description</a>
 </li>
 <p><!-- E 4-5 -7-8-9-10-11 --></p>
</ul>
```

**Problem:** When I use `find_all()` to extract all the `<ul>` - I am not getting it due the malformed ending `</p>` which has missing opening `<p>`. Browser ignores this and renders ok but BS4 messes up the parsing. Did anyone try to ignore any malformed tags in BS4 if present?

```
entries = soup.find_all(lambda x: x.name == 'ul')
print(len(entries))
print(entries[0])

1
<ul>
 <!-- C 1-3 --></ul>
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you should try a more lenient parser for the HTML.  For example:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(pg, "html5lib")
```

For the html5lib parser is the most lenient parser.  The advantages are:

- Extremely lenient
- Parses pages the same way a web browser does
- Creates valid HTML5

Disadvantages are:

- Very slow
- External Python dependency

The documentation offers some explanation of the pros and cons of different parsers: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#installing-a-parser

Comment: FWIW, you should quote the relevant text in case the link changes for whatever reason. :-)